# Fetching array data from database in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a table "config" with three fields

```
------------------
id | name | value
------------------
 1 | na1  | va1 
 2 | na2  | va2
 3 | na3  | va3
 . | ...  | ...
```

I need to fetch the above data to an array "$confData" as given below

```
$confData ===>

  array(
   'na1' => 'va1',
   'na2' => 'va2',
   'na1' => 'va3',
   ' . ' => '...'
  );
```

I want to know wether there is any predefined function/method in symfony-doctrine to get this array? If it is not available, how can use doctrine way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such default way. You should build this array manually for fetched object.

```
//after fetching $objectCollection

$config = array();
foreach ($objectCollection as $object) {
    $config[$object->getName()] = $object->getValue();
}
```